# Is there a standard set of exit code numbers for C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, exit, exit-code

AFAIK, the exit code numbers may vary depending on the application and the conventions adopted in a project. However, I wonder if there is an exit code standard list for C/C++ projects.

Comment: For Linux, googling gave me https://linuxconfig.org/list-of-exit-codes-on-linux.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica That is for Unisx shell scripting. I am looking for C/C++

Comment: @RubemPacelli *"That is for Unisx shell scripting. I am looking for C/C++"* -- Correct. The exit codes from a C++ program are used by other programs, often shell scripts or the equivalent.

Comment: @RubemPacelli The exit status of a process is the exit status of a process.  What language that process was written in doesn't matter.

Comment: Incidentally, they are identical. Shell script, built-in or binary: They all follow, for good reason, the same convention. Note that apart from 0, none of them is mandatory (even 0 is not *mandatory* -- there is no Linux police so you can return what you like -- but it's not recommended to return 0 if not successful and vice versa). And: Apart from built-in commands, shell scripts eventually return the exit code of some binary.

Comment: @dbush A shell script does not necessarily run in its own shell and can still return something.

Comment: @dbush "*What language that process was written in doesn't matter.*" -- I've noticed that exit code number may considerably vary depending on the programming language you adopt. If we go beyond the "zero is success, non-zero is error", we see that the conventions between languages do not match.

Comment: @RubemPacelli How do you know if your program was written in Fortran or in Cobol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Program exit codes

Short answer: no, except for `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`, which are defined in `stdlib.h`. See here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/EXIT_status.

From the community wiki link above:

> **Notes**
>
> Both `EXIT_SUCCESS` and the value zero indicate successful program execution status (see [exit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/exit)), although it is not required that `EXIT_SUCCESS` equals zero.

### Function return codes

Also no.

But, most functions have a description which can be looked up on https://en.cppreference.com/w/ (a rather thorough community wiki) or https://cplusplus.com/ (also a community wiki) to help you know what the return values should be.

### [`errno`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/errno) error numbers assigned to the `errno` global variable when a function call fails or has an error

Also no, but most systems will provide a "standardized" set of error numbers for that system.

*But*, `errno` error numbers are intended to be used by the *caller* of the function which returned the error. They are *not* intended to be returned as error codes when a program crashes.

From [@John Bollinger's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77689011/is-there-a-standard-set-of-exit-code-numbers-for-c-c/77689046#comment136963724_77689040):

> Error numbers are values that are communicated to the caller of the function that encountered the error, via the `errno` variable or as the function return value, depending on the function. Neither are they meant for use as program exit statuses nor is there any convention of using them that way.

I typically print the `errno` value when a function call fails so that the code author or user can debug the run-time crash. Printing the `errno` value, and a human-readable description of it via `strerror(errno)`, might be done like this:

```c
#include <errno.h>   // `errno`
#include <string.h>  // `strerror(errno)`

// ...

// in some function:

int retcode = clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
if (retcode == -1)
{
    printf("Failed to get a timestamp. errno = %i: %s\n",
        errno, strerror(errno));
}
```

You can see that usage in my program here, for instance: [timing_clock_gettime_full_demo.c](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/timing_clock_gettime_full_demo.c) in my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo.

**Examples of where `errno`s are defined, for various systems**:

1. **For Linux:** https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html:

   Notice that in these error names, they also indicate if it is part of the POSIX standard (`POSIX.1-2001` or `POSIX.1-2008`), or part of the `C99` standard.

   The actual error numbers can be tracked down via the `errno.h` header file, which may include other files. Example: here are some of the error number definitions on Linux:

   1. https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno.h, which includes:
   2. https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno-base.h
2. **For Microchip PIC32M microcontrollers:**

   You can see the error codes in `<errno.h>` here: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/Microchip_XC32_Compiler/blob/main/xc32-v4.35-src/pic32m-source/newlib/newlib/libc/include/errno.h

   Which includes `<sys/errno.h>` here, where the error numbers are actually defined: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/Microchip_XC32_Compiler/blob/main/xc32-v4.35-src/pic32m-source/newlib/newlib/libc/include/sys/errno.h

### See also

1. `strerror(errno)` provides a description string of a given error code/number. See here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strerror

Comment: But as discussed under the OP's own answer, the `errno` values from library function calls are not typically used as program exit values, are they?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica, agreed.

Answer (score 6):

A far as C++ itself goes, there are only three values, specifying two conditions: `0`, `EXIT_FAILURE`, and `EXIT_SUCCESS`.

`0` and `EXIT_SUCCESS` both give implementation defined indications of successful exit. They're both described the same way in the standard, but there's no guarantee that they'll actually be the same value (though they are on most typical platforms).

`EXIT_FAILURE` gives an implementation defined indication of failure.

Anything else is up to the platform. Most of the common platforms like Linux, Windows, MacOS and *BSD will preserve at least the 8 least significant bits being returned to the shell.

Comment: Is it up to the platform? It is *certainly* up to the program; do programs change their exit codes depending on the platform they have been compiled for or on which they are running?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: yes. For example, 0 is required to signal success but on VMS odd numbers mean success and even numbers mean failure, so if you do `exit(0)` or `return 0;` from `main`, that zero will be transformed into some odd number.

Comment: Oh my :-). Thanks. Interesting: It provides the possibility to distinguish between different modes of success.

Answer (score 0):

> AFAIK, the exit code numbers may vary depending on the application and the conventions adopted in a project.

And, importantly, on the conventions of the host system.

> However, I wonder if there is a exit code standard list for C/C++ projects.

C itself takes care to *avoid* declaring any such thing, except that exit status 0 communicates success.  Other than that, it specifies macros `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`, whose (unspecified) values communicate program success and program failure, respectively.

The POSIX specifications for the shell command language do specify [a few exit statuses for shell commands](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_08_02).  That would fall into the category of host system conventions, and at least on POSIX systems, it is wise to avoid exit statuses that conflict with those.